# How to send an invalid transaction for testing purposes?

Tags: testnet, transaction-verification, testing, regtest, validation

How could I send an invalid transaction—for testing purposes, such as with testnet or regtest?

For example, I would like to to try to double-spend, spend non existent coins, etc.

Comment: Using createrawtransaction without using signrawtransaction seems like it would work.

Comment: @NickODell Transactions don't have to be signed?

Comment: Not if you don't care about them being valid. createrawtransaction will give you empty signature fields.